# im a big c++ noob and I need help starting out a block of code for my program

Tags: c++

so i am making a code that takes data from a txt file and gets its variance.
The formula that my teacher required us to use needs the program to square the decimals in the txt file and then gets its sum. unfortunately i do not have a sample of code because I do not know where to start. I was only able to store the data in the text file into a vector.

```
ifstream dataInput("D:\\Users\\Rodolfo Obre\\Documents\\Ateneo De Manila\\Intersession 2019\\Engg 21\\Programs\\Text Files\\Data Set.txt");
double readNumber;
vector<double> dataSet;

if (!dataInput.is_open()) {
    cerr << "The file can not be opened\n";
    exit(1);//exits the program
}

while (dataInput >> readNumber){
        dataSet.push_back(readNumber);
}
cout << "n is equal to " << dataSet.size() << endl;

double sum=0;
for (int i=0; i < dataSet.size(); i++){
    sum += dataSet[i];
}
cout << "The sum of the data is " << sum << endl;
```

This block of code takes the data from the txt file, counts how many there are and then takes its sum.

I have no idea how I to do the part where i need to take each decimal in the text file, raise it to the power 2 and then get the sum of all of the values.

Comment: You're going to need to work on getting a start on this and post back when you have a specific question regarding code you've written.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a tutorial site.

Comment: Please make your title relevant / specific to the problem you're having not just "please help"

Comment: What do you mean by "the decimals"?  Do you mean all the values?  If so, you can remember that `x²` is the same as `x*x` - and just multiply the value with itself.

Comment: Also, if you calculate `sum` and `sumOfSquares` as you read the numbers in, you won't have to save the individual values in a vector - this will speed your code up quite a bit.

Comment: If you do not know where to start, you need a conversation with your teacher and/or lab assistant. That's what they're there for. SO isn't for mentoring. Good luck!

Comment: if you have to calculate the variance you need more than just the sum of squared numbers. You first have to calculate the mean. Only if the mean is 0, summing the squares will give you the variance directly

Answer (score 2):

You need to sum the sqaures of the numbers? You don't even need a vector to do this because you can sum the numbers and sum their squares as you read them. There's no need to store anything in a vector

```
double sum = 0.0;
double sumOfSquares = 0.0;
int count = 0;
while (dataInput >> readNumber) {
    sum += readNumber; // add the read number to the sum
    sumOfSquares += readNumber*readNumber; // square the read number, add to the sum of squares
    ++count; // count how many numbers so far
}
```

You have to get used to taking a problem and working out how to translate that problem into original code. Not adapting something similar but writing truly original code. So by all means use this code but soon but you will have to get to the stage where you can devise code for yourself.

Comment: Note how john does not use `pow(readNumber,2)` to square the input. `pow` is designed to do the really hard stuff like computing e to the power of pi and is often vast, and time-consuming, overkill for something as simple as squaring.

Comment: to get the variance, either two passes are needed or a less numerically stable formula has to be used. Actually I do not completely understand the question. If OP only needs to calculate the sum of squares then maybe the numbers are already the difference to the mean of the actual samples...

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Maybe two passes are needed, in that case storing in a vector is correct. I've just answered the question asked, but maybe the OP has asked the wrong question.

Comment: yes actually nothing wrong with your answer, maybe I should have put the comment under the quesiton instead of your answer